# Auto change comma for dot, Spanish language in Magento2

Tags: magento2, price, format

I have a problem with catalog price.

If my product price is $1,989.89

I want Magento to auto change `,` to `.` and display price this way.
[image]

My XML for es_MX is:

> Magento/zendframework1/library/zend/Locale/data/es_MX.xml

```
<numbers>
    <symbols numberSystem="latn">
        <decimal draft="contributed">.</decimal>
        <group draft="contributed">,</group>
        <percentSign draft="contributed">%</percentSign>
        <plusSign draft="contributed">+</plusSign>
        <minusSign draft="contributed">-</minusSign>
        <exponential draft="contributed">E</exponential>
        <superscriptingExponent draft="contributed">×</superscriptingExponent>
        <perMille draft="contributed">‰</perMille>
        <infinity draft="contributed">∞</infinity>
        <nan draft="contributed">NaN</nan>
    </symbols>
    <decimalFormats numberSystem="latn">
        <decimalFormatLength>
            <decimalFormat>
                <pattern draft="contributed">#,##0.###</pattern>
            </decimalFormat>
        </decimalFormatLength>
```

Help me to fix !!!

Comment: You tried this way? http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/148249/33057